# How to access a property from an inner class in an outer class?

Tags: c#

here is some code :

```
public class TimerEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Timer Timer { get; }
    public ClockTimer.TimerTimes Times { get; }
    public DateTime? RunTime { get; }

    public TimerEventArgs(Timer Timer, ClockTimer.TimerTimes Times, DateTime? RunTime)
    {
        this.Timer = Timer;
        this.Times = Times;
        this.RunTime = RunTime;
    }
}

public class ClockTimer
{
    public class TimerTimes
    {
        public DateTime? Start { get; private set; }
        public TimeSpan? RunDuration { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? Stop { get; private set; }

        public TimerTimes()
            : this(null, null, null)
        {}

        public TimerTimes(DateTime? Start, TimeSpan? RunDuration, DateTime? Stop)
        {
            this.Start = Start;
            this.RunDuration = RunDuration;
            this.Stop = Stop;
        }
    }
    :
    private TimerTimes m_TimerTimes = null;
    :
    public virtual void Start()
    {
        // Start timer if not running.
        if (!IsRunning)
        {
            if (m_Timer == null)
                m_Timer = new Timer();
            m_Timer.Interval = Interval;
            m_Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(InnerTimerHandler);

            if (m_TimerTimes == null)
                m_TimerTimes = new TimerTimes();
            m_TimerTimes.Start = DateTime.Now;  //Property Start is inaccesssable!!

            m_Timer.Start();

            TimerEventArgs EventArgs = new TimerEventArgs(m_Timer, m_TimerTimes);

            OnTimerStarted(EventArgs);
        }
    }
    :
}
```

Is there a way to "set" a property from an inner class in an outer class, but not allow it to be set from outside? Only the outer class must be capable to set the inner class property.

Comment: Could you specify your purpose? Which property do you mean? Give a sample please

Comment: The line : m_TimerTimes.Start = DateTime.Now;

Comment: Your code is very incomplete, can't copy-paste as a working sample. And it contains much noise unnecessary for the problem

Comment: make the setter of the property "Start" public, but let the instance of the inner class private (as done in your example)

Comment: I know. It is just a fragment that illustrates my problem. The rest is of no importance.

Comment: you can make the class TimerTimes as private class, so they can't be accessed outside and remove the private in the set

Comment: I extended my code a little bit. The ClockTimer.TimerTimes class gets exposed through a TimerEventArgs object in an outside event handler. Is it not possible now to change the Start property inside this handler when I make the TimerTimes.Start setter public ?

Comment: @Ron if you follow my answer, `TimerEventArgs` would contain `public ClockTimer.ITimerTimes Times` and this would only expose the getter for the `Start` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `private` inner class with public properties / methods that are accessible to the outer class but not to anything further outside. If you want part of the inner class to be public, derive the private inner class from some sort of public interface (which can be an `interface`, `class` or `abstract class` depending on your needs).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new ClockTimer();
        t.Start();
        var date = t.TimerTimesInstance.Start; // getter Ok
        t.TimerTimesInstance.Start = DateTime.Now; // Error! setter denied
    }
}
public class ClockTimer
{
    public interface ITimerTimes
    {
        DateTime? Start { get; }
    }
    private class TimerTimes : ITimerTimes
    {
        public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
    }

    private TimerTimes m_TimerTimes = null;
    public virtual void Start()
    {
        m_TimerTimes = new TimerTimes();
        m_TimerTimes.Start = DateTime.Now;  //Property Start is assessible here
    }

    public ITimerTimes TimerTimesInstance { get { return m_TimerTimes; } }
}
```

As you see, i reduced the example a bit, but all necessary code should be in it.

Comment: Why `abstract`?

Comment: @rbr94 Cause as it is `Start` makes no sense without an implementation that actually sets its value somewhere. The `abstract` is not strictly necessary, its only showing the intended usage.

Comment: @grek40 it could also be an interface

Comment: @zerkms Agreed, guess I'll edit the question to make clear, that its just about some public accessible part and a private local accessible part. No matter whether its `interface`, `class` or `abstract class`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a property from an outside class, use public for the operation you want to use. In your case you can only read the property `get;` and not write or change it with `set`:

```
public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
```

The same is applied to your nested class. If you want to access **TimerTimes** outside of **ClockTimer** leave it as `public`, otherwise set it to `private` to only permit **ClockTimer** to access it (shortended example):

```
public class ClockTimer {

    private class TimerTimes {
        public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
    }

    public ClockTimer() {
        var timerTimes = new TimerTimes();
        timerTimes.Start = DateTime.Now;
    } 
}
```

Comment: The actual question is different. Read it again.